# My script never runs the content of my if statement but i dont get any error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to use code to swing a weapon back and forth on key down, for some reason nothing happens though. I've tested the various bits of code by running it separately and i got all my statements to work with a bit of changes here and there. But I just cant figure out how to fit them all together and have them all running. Appreciate any pointers!

```
public float BackRotationsSpeed = 100f;
public float ForwardRotationSpeed = 300f;


// Use this for initialization                                                                              // Original rotation cordinates of sword (-1.523,86.914,8.212)          
void Start () {
                                                                                                            // Rotation kan foregå på left right up down forward backwards
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {                                                                            

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.U) && transform.eulerAngles.z > 8.2 && transform.eulerAngles.z < 8.3)          // Checks if sword is in its original location, and if it is swing backwards.
    {       
        transform.Rotate (Vector3.forward, -BackRotationsSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }


    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.U) && transform.eulerAngles.z > 70 && transform.eulerAngles.z < 200)           // Checks if sword has reached furthest back point before swining forward + triple the speed swinging forward for extra oomf!
    {
        transform.Rotate (Vector3.forward, ForwardRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);  
    }


    if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.U) &&transform.eulerAngles.z>8.3 && transform.eulerAngles.z<70)                 // Checks if sword has reached furthest forward point in the forward swing, if it is reset the rotation to its origin and wait for next attack command 
    {
        Vector3 temp = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
        temp.z = 8.21f;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(temp);
    }
```

Comment: When you put a breakpoint and move step by step does not your code goes into any if statements?

Comment: you will get a deadlock when getting your z angle is lower 8.2.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is running the first "if" statement which rotates the sword to around 6.5 degrees (assuming 30fps).  After that, 6.5 is outside of the range for any of your if statements, so nothing else happens.

My pointer would be to use the attack key to set the DESIRED rotation, then have each frame update rotate toward that position based on it's current rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Try pulling the Input key statement away from the others like below, also try to account for the angles that are not listed, if the sword falls into that area you will not get a response anymore.

Don't forget that there are negative angles, and they can give you a real hard time to work with them. Multiple different numbers can account for the exact same orientation, sometimes the number will drop back to 0 after 90 or so so just make sure you are debugging all your angles and checking the floats yourself.

```
public float BackRotationsSpeed = 100f;
public float ForwardRotationSpeed = 300f;


// Use this for initialization        
void Start () {
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {                                                                            
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.U))
    {
        if (transform.eulerAngles.z > 8.2 && transform.eulerAngles.z < 8.3)          // Checks if sword is in its original location, and if it is swing backwards.
        {       
            transform.Rotate (Vector3.forward, -BackRotationsSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }


        if (transform.eulerAngles.z > 70 && transform.eulerAngles.z < 200)           // Checks if sword has reached furthest back point before swining forward + triple the speed swinging forward for extra oomf!
        {
            transform.Rotate (Vector3.forward, ForwardRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);  
        }


        if(transform.eulerAngles.z>8.3 && transform.eulerAngles.z<70)                 // Checks if sword has reached furthest forward point in the forward swing, if it is reset the rotation to its origin and wait for next attack command 
        {
            Vector3 temp = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
            temp.z = 8.21f;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(temp);
        }
    }
}
```